# Monitor traffic to Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to monitor traffic to an Azure Load balancer. To this end I opened the Monitor blade in Azure and added the "Inbound bytes DDoS" metric for my load balancer and Public IP instance.

Unfortunately nothing ever appears on the chart, it is always empty. Is there another metric or method I should be using to monitor traffic to my load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another metric or method I should be using to monitor
>   traffic to my load balancer?

From your description, I suppose you have a public Standard load balancer. If you want to know log analytics for public Basic Load Balancer, you can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log).

For Standard load balancer, Azure provides new multiple-dimensional metric via the Metrics in the Azure portal, and it helps you get real-time diagnostic insights into your load balancer resources. You can see [these metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#a-name--multidimensionalmetricsamulti-dimensional-metrics) provided by Standard Load Balancer configurations.

For example, you could use the **Data Path Availability** metric to monitor the external availability of your service and the **Health Probe Status** metric to determine where to send new flows. By using a combination of the VIP availability and health probe metrics on a single chart you can identify where to look for the problem and resolve the problem. 
The **SNAT connections metric** describes the volume of successful and failed connections for outbound flows. Use **SYN packets** (Packet Count, SYN Count) metric to understand TCP connection attempts to your service.

> The VIP availability metric describes the health of the data path
>   within the region to the compute host where your VMs are located. The
>   metric is a reflection of the health of the Azure infrastructure. You
>   can use the metric to:
>
> - Monitor the external availability of your service
> - Dig deeper and understand whether the platform on which your service is deployed is healthy or whether your guest OS or application
>     instance is healthy.
> - Isolate whether an event is related to your service or the underlying data plane. Do not confuse this metric with the health
>     probe status ("DIP availability").
>
> The health probe status metric describes the health of your
>   application deployment as configured by you when you configure the
>   health probe of your load balancer. The load balancer uses the status
>   of the health probe to determine where to send new flows. Health
>   probes originate from an Azure infrastructure address and are visible
>   within the guest OS of the VM.

More details: [Common diagnostic scenarios and recommended views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#a-name--diagnosticscenariosacommon-diagnostic-scenarios-and-recommended-views)

Answer (score 0):

When you mean "monitor" are you using Azure Monitor or the Monitor(diagnostics) blade of the Loadbalancer?

If you have opted for the standard DDoS protection plan, you'd seem them populate for the respective public IP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-ddos-protection

So please make sure
1. You have Azure Standard DDoS Plan for the VNet and Public IPs
2. The telemetry configured for Azure Monitor

This should give you the desired metrics for DDoS.

You can't view them over the standard LB blades and what can essentially view are described in the above post.